# Excel Phone Number Formatting

Tags: excel, formatting, vba

I have a column in "Phone Number"(O2). The column has phone numbers from multiple countries, countries are located in the column left to O2 i.e. N2.
Phone numbers are in below format:

1. 61-387870303
2. 61-386551781
3. 089420-0222
4. 395666269
5. 61388233240

Minus the serial number, I didn't knew how to get a list here without serial numbers.
So my problem is there is no common character for me to split the characters into, I could use "61-" but it won't work in all the column, nor a "61" would work as some of them don't have country codes. Nor the number of characters in the phone number is same, some are 8 digit, some are 15.
And this is only for Australia, I have many countries other than this.
Number formatting won't work I guess, some kind of Macro will be needed.

Comment: You have to decide on a common format that satisfies **you**. Different countries have different phone number formats and some countries have different formats for mobile vs. land line. Find a format that **you** see as appropriate and use that. Trying to abide by each country's idiosyncrasies is a fool's errand as there will be differences even within a country.

Comment: You can only **format** them alike if they are entered alike. For this purpose the international phone number format [E.164](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164) has been developed which generally states that phone numbers should be entered such as *[+][country code][subscriber number including area code]*. Yet, it seems (at least to me) that your phone numbers don't follow any particular format when they were entered. So, I wonder how you want to format them alike using one format only.

Comment: What would be your desired output for these 5 numbers? can you update that as well in the question

Comment: The problem here is that the number of characters in the string differs on a wide range. I have string lengths of 5 to 15. And that too vary from country to country, thus the desired output is not possible to get from simple solutions. I will post the desired result in a while, travelling now.

Comment: 61-387-870-303
61-386-551-781
44-089-420-0222
39-566-6269
61-388-233-240

Basically I have the list of countries in the adjacent column, so I can get the country codes for them using a lookup table that I have with me, but  some numbers already have country code while others don't. I don't need them to follow a particular pattern per se, but one country should have one format. That is what I am trying to achieve.